# Can't see ATrace logs in logcat

Tags: android, systrace

I used the tracing mechanism for C++ described [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/tracing) by google. I'm checking for ATrace_isEnabled and while I'm getting true for ATrace_isEnabled, I'm unable to see any logs in the logcat.

I also went through with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076751/atrace-isenabled-return-false) answer, but to get enabled, I have to run systrace.py --app="my binary name". The setting of flags do not help

Is there something I'm missing?

I'm on Android 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

The setting of flags do not help, because in there source code, logic is such that it gets changed to `0` again. You need to specify appname wise like

`adb shell "setprop debug.atrace.app_number 1"
 adb shell "setprop debug.atrace.app_0 appname"`

and for getting logs in logcat, use this `__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "ATrace_isEnabled = %s", ATrace_isEnabled1()?"true":"false");`. Define LOG_TAG for this.
for more help, see this [ATrace_isEnabled() return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076751/atrace-isenabled-return-false)

Comment: This is just part of the problem. More info: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/systrace/custom-events#native-code
In Android Studio/DDMS, one has to enable a flag in the settings file to see them in systrace. I forgot which one